# get the string with blank

Tags: c, string

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, i, k = 0, M = 0, N, count = 0, ave;
    char a[10000] = { 0 };
    int m[10000] = { 0 };
    scanf("%d", &i);
    while (i--)
    {
        while (k< 10000) {
                a[k] = 0;
                k++;
            }
        scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
        k = 0;
        n = 0;
        printf("%s", a);
    }
}
```

I want to get string but `scanf()` doesn't work.
I can't guess why it doesn't work can you help me please?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &i);` leaves a newline (`\n`) in the input buffer. Then, that is all `scanf("%[^\n]s", a);` sees and returns nothing. Try adding `getchar();` before the `scanf` to consume the newline.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Why not write an answer? `getchar()` is not the most elegant way around this, though.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]s", a);`  After the `%[...]` the next character will be '\n', NEVER a `s` Suggest removing that `s`

Comment: OT: regarding: `while (k< 10000) {
                a[k] = 0;
                k++;
            }`  much better to use: `memset( a, '\0', sizeof( a ) );`  Note: `memset()` is exposed via the statement: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: to have `scanf("%[^\n]", a);` not get involved with any leftover white space in `stdin`, include a space before the `input format conversion` specifier, I.E. `scanf(" %[^\n]", a);`

Comment: Stop using `scanf()`.  Use `fgets()` is read all lines of user input.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &i);` leaves a newline (`\n`) in the input buffer. Then, that is all `scanf("%[^\n]s", a);` sees and returns nothing. There are a few ways to work around this. Here's one:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char a[10000];
    // Always check the return value from scanf
    if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Consume the newline scanf left
    // It might be easier just to use fgets here.....
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "getchar failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    while (i--)
    {
        // Use fgets to get the entire line instead of scanf
        if (fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fgets failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // Note that fgets leaves the newline. Need to remove it
        a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `puts("Error...");
            return 0;`  this is an error exit.  So should indicate an error, not success.  Suggest: `return 1;`  and error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "fgets failed\n" );`  --OR-- `fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );`

Comment: @user3629249  Thanks for the feedback. I have implemented your suggestions.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks also for the feedback. I have implemented your suggestion.